# PHP $_GET and $_POST code not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, variables

I have some PHP code and when executed the code doesn't send the values to the other PHP page on my site.  My permissions are 755.

Page 1:

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bay Area Buckets</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
  <style>

  .navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
    z-index: 9999;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    line-height: 1.42857143 !important;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
    color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
    color: #f4511e !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: transparent;
    color: #fff !important;
}
.resize {
   border: 2px solid;
    padding: 20px; 

    resize: vertical;
    overflow: auto;


}
textarea {
    width: 100%;
}

  </style>
</head>
<body>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
     <a href="index"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CnvlpmKUAAArtx_.png:large" alt="Logo" height="60" width="60"></a> 
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

     <li><a href="index">HOME</a></li><li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
        <li><a href="about">ABOUT</a></li><li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
        <li><a href="hats">HATS</a></li><li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
        <li><a href="socialMedia">SOCIAL MEDIA</a></li><li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
        <li><a href="cart">Cart</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
    <div>
        <center><h1 ><span style="color:#ff6666;">Contact Us</span></h1></center>
    </div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<?php
echo '<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <form action="contact.php" method="post">
    Name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="name"/ >
    Email: 
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="email"/>
    Message:
    <br>
    <textarea class="riseize" value="text" name="message"></textarea>
    <br>
    <center><input type="submit" value="submit"/></center>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>'
?>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Calls contact.php which is:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO help (name, email, message) VALUES ( '$name' , '$email' , '$message' )";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
else {
echo "<html><script language='JavaScript'> alert('Thank you for your submission.'),window.location = 'index'</script></html>";
};
```

I think the problem is the get $_GET and $_POST because it executes contact.php and calls the variable values, but it doesn't get the values from the page 1.

Comment: Your form uses POST, so you have to use $_POST to get the values passed to it. You are using $_GET.

Comment: Side note, since you aren't putting any variables into your script in the `Page 1` snippet, you don't have to `echo` it using php, just put the html.

Comment: Another note - you don't use `<h5>`, you use `<label for="id-of-input-element">`- create the form properly, please. Also - the contact.php-file - does it actually start with `<?php`?

Comment: Sorry about the messy code, I was testing different formating, and the contact.php starts with <?php

Comment: `<textarea>` btw doesn't have a "type", it has value.

Comment: Looks like you have some sort of an issue on the php.ini make sure the post_max_size is set to a correct value ie. 8M and not 10MB which gets interpreted to 0

Comment: On your contact.php page, do this: `print_r($_POST);`. What does it show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You close the form when you open it. Change:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" />
```

to:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
```

the `/` closes the element, basically you have

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post"></form>
```

then all your other inputs go to nothing.

(Other issues mentioned also are true, but this is why your form is empty)

In your browser you also should use the developer console (location and options vary by browser) to see how the request is sent and processed. https://wpscholar.com/blog/view-form-data-in-chrome/ This will show you first if it is an issue with the form sending, or the PHP processing it (e.g. if the values aren't sent you know it is not a PHP issue).

As it turned out in this case you had a rewrite in place that stripped the `.php`, also removing parameters. Making a direct request to the page, bypassing the rewrite rule resolved this.

```
action="contact"
```

Comment: I am on GoDaddy hosting and they are both on .php files.  I used `print_r($_POST);` on contact.php to check the values and there are none in POST array

Comment: where would I put echo

Comment: I get the form on the webpage when I go to my site.  In the headers it thinks I am sending a get request

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I hide all .php and .html at the end of my site's address for all addresses.  This causes my code to run /contact.php and then tries /contact , but /contact doesn't receive the data from page 1.  Simple mistake.

Comment: yes that worked! thank you so much for your help and sorry for wasting a lot of your time for such a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your form uses `method="post"` so the inputs will be sent to the PHP script in the `$_POST` array

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" />
                                   ^^^^
```

So change these 2 lines to use `$_POST`

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
```

BUT

> Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
>   Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
>   [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

AND

> Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
>    database extension in new code
>    **[this happens](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)**
>    it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
>   If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
>   [Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: that change did not work.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Ok, so do a `print_r($_POST);` at the top of your script. What do you get

Comment: I got "Array ()"

Comment: You are running this through a web server I suppose and not double clicking a file in explorer

Comment: Yes this is going through a web server

Comment: is my code wrong for a web server? I am using godaddy

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're trying to pass using post by in the file contact.php you are getting by get the name and the email

If you want to pass your values by post you must get it all by post

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

If you want to do it by get you must get it all by get

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" />
```

In your form you are using post

Comment: how should I fix it